# What are the benefits of using Task<> & await to load items into a view

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am working through some example UoW patterns and have come across this:

```
public interface ICustomerService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetAsync();
}

// GET: /Customer/
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _customerService.GetAsync());
}
```

I understand tasks are used for performing async actions but does `GetAsync` have any advantage over just declaring it as `IEnumerable` here (because of the use of `await`) or does this mean it can return the view immediately and the `Customer` objects can be loaded in the background whilst the view is rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not return the view immediately, [as I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

Rather, on ASP.NET, the benefit of asynchronous requests is *scalability*. While the call to the customer service is in flight, the request thread is freed up to do other work, e.g., handle another request. When the `await` completes, another request thread is picked up to complete the original request, returning the actual view.

For more information, see the [slides from my recent CodeMash talk](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/01/achievement-unlocked-speak-at-codemash.html).

Comment: That makes sense and is inline with what I was thinking (Bad choice of words when I said return the view immediately). I'm assuming that this would be a best practice? Are there any situations where this could turn around and bite me?

Comment: It's a best practice in general, but there are situations where it won't help. E.g., if every request hit a single SQL Server backend, then your scalability bottleneck is the DB, not the web server. Also, there are two notable problems with MVC today: it does not support async filters nor async child actions. Regular actions are fine. Finally, I recommend taking a `CancellationToken` as described in my slides and [the online tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).